# Centos - Cannot find what cause file increase

Tags: linux, centos

Currently i am facing problem that the centos is running out of space. I have checked the size by using command 'df -h' . It stated that 34GB storage size and used 32GB. However when i execute "command du -sh /*", the actually used file size is less than 1 GB.
[image]

[image]

Comment: where is the /var and /usr size?

Comment: The /var = 686M and /usr=900M,
[root@in ~]# du -sh /var
686M    /var , 
[root@in ~]# du -sh /usr
900M    /usr

Comment: whats the output of `lsof | grep deleted`?

Comment: Hi Rui F Ribeiro, i have update the image to content lsof | grep delete. Btw, i  did kill the process on yesterday. Result still same.

Comment: Please do not use images to display text. What do you think of the last line? Is it in a mounted system or local?

Comment: I tried to paste into text, but all the text is joining. Quite messy to view.
The last line  /mnt is mounted folder. Even i ran the command kill process, the used space still remain the same.